# Namespace and Simple_Form Hitting The Right Controller/Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form on a cart page to update line_items.  So the resource I am updating needs to exit the cart controller and enter the line_items controller...    I am using the following form...

```
<%= simple_form_for shifted_commerce_line_item_path(item), 
:url => {controller: 'line_items', action: 'update'} do |f| %>
```

I get no route matches...

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"shifted_commerce/line_items"}
```

The thing is... I have the the action in the controller...

I'll post my routes.

```
     shifted_commerce_line_items GET    /shifted_commerce/line_items(.:format)          shifted_commerce/line_items#index
                                 POST   /shifted_commerce/line_items(.:format)          shifted_commerce/line_items#create
  new_shifted_commerce_line_item GET    /shifted_commerce/line_items/new(.:format)      shifted_commerce/line_items#new
 edit_shifted_commerce_line_item GET    /shifted_commerce/line_items/:id/edit(.:format) shifted_commerce/line_items#edit
      shifted_commerce_line_item GET    /shifted_commerce/line_items/:id(.:format)      shifted_commerce/line_items#show
                                 PATCH  /shifted_commerce/line_items/:id(.:format)      shifted_commerce/line_items#update
                                 PUT    /shifted_commerce/line_items/:id(.:format)      shifted_commerce/line_items#update
                                 DELETE /shifted_commerce/line_items/:id(.:format)      shifted_commerce/line_items#destroy
```

How do I get this form to hit the update action in my controller?

Don't we see the above route? both PUT and PATCH match /shifted_commerce/Line_items/:id...and I'm passing the id with the (item)...

**Update 1** I'll also add that I'm running this form in a loop, so every line_item can be edited.  @anything isn't what I'd want to pass to the path for an ID... also, I'm operating from the carts controller, in the show action.  Not a line_item controller, edit action.

**Update 2**  If I do the following simple_form_for:

```
    <%= simple_form_for shifted_commerce_line_item_path(item), :url => {controller: 'line_items', action: 'create'} do |f| %>
```

It successfully takes me into the create action of the line_items controller. But if I do

```
    <%= simple_form_for shifted_commerce_line_item_path(item), :url => {controller: 'line_items', action: 'update'} do |f| %>
```

I get the route error. What's the deal?! **Why does it work for create but not for update?** I have the update action in my controller...

ShiftedCommerce::LineItemsController

```
   class ShiftedCommerce::LineItemsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :set_line_item_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /line_items
      # GET /line_items.json
      def index
        @line_items = ShiftedCommerce::LineItem.all
      end

      # GET /line_items/1
      # GET /line_items/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /line_items/new
      def new
        @line_item = ShiftedCommerce::LineItem.new
      end

      # GET /line_items/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /line_items
      # POST /line_items.json
      def create
        @cart = current_cart
        # item is built from base_item, after finding associated product
          @base_item_id = params[:shifted_commerce_line_item][:base_item_id]
        get_item_id_from_base_item_params
          build_line_item

          ## Does a line item with the same itemt_id already exist in cart?
          if @line_item.exists_in_collect?(current_cart.line_items)
            #if so, change quantity, check if there's enough stock
              if  current_cart.where_line_item_with(@item_id).update_quantity(@line_item.quantity) == true
                @line_item.destroy
                redirect_to shifted_commerce_base_items_path
                flash[:success] = "Detected item In Cart,  Added Your Amount More to Quantity"
              else #otherwise there's not enough product in stock.
                redirect_to shifted_commerce_cart_path
                flash[:failure] = "Cannot Add To Cart, Not Enough In Stock"
              end
          else # This product isn't in the cart already let's save it!
            if @line_item.have_enough_item? == true # if there is enough stock, save
              if @line_item.save
                respond_to do |format|
                format.html { redirect_to shifted_commerce_base_items_path, 
                  :notice => "Added to Cart." }
                format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
                  :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
                end
              else
                format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
                  :status => :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            else # not enough stock, not saved.
              redirect_to shifted_commerce_base_items_path
              if @line_item.item.stock_qty > 0
              flash[:failure] = "Sorry! We Only Don't Have Enough In Stock"
              else
              flash[:failure] = "Sorry! That Item Is Out Stock"
              end
            end 
          end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
      # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
      def update
      @line_item = ShiftedCommerce::LineItem.find(params[:id])
      raise
        @line_item.attributes = line_item_params
          if @line_item.over_order_cap? #is the quantity over maximum?
            flash[:error] = "Contact Us For Orders of This Size -- Quantity Set To Max"
            redirect_to cart_path
          else # quantity to change to not over maximum.
            if @line_item.have_enough_item? == true
               @line_item.update(line_item_params)
               #did they update quantity to 0?
                if @line_item.quantity <= 0
                   @line_item.destroy
                      flash[:success] = "Item Removed"
                      redirect_to :back
                else  
                      flash[:success] = "Itemed Updated"
                      redirect_to cart_path
                end
            else
              redirect_to cart_path
              flash[:failure] = "We Don't Have Enough In Stock.  Update Failed"
            end
          end
      end

      # DELETE /line_items/1
      # DELETE /line_items/1.json
      def destroy
        @line_item.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to line_items_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_line_item
          @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
        end
        def set_line_item_item
          @line_item_name = @line_item.item.base_item
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def line_item_params
          params.fetch(:shifted_commerce_line_item, {}).permit(:item_id, :cart_id, :order_id, :quantity, :weight, :units)
        end
        def build_line_item
          @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(
            :item_id => @item_id,
            :order_id => nil,
            :weight => params[:shifted_commerce_line_item][:weight],
            :quantity => params[:shifted_commerce_line_item][:quantity]
            )
        end
        def get_item_id_from_base_item_params

          @item_id = ShiftedCommerce::Item.where(:base_item_id => @base_item_id).where(:size_id => params[:shifted_commerce_line_item][:size]).first.id
        end
    end
```

line_item.rb

```
   class ShiftedCommerce::LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :item
      belongs_to :cart
      after_create :set_order_weight#, :set_package_dimentions
      after_update :set_order_weight#, :set_package_dimentions
        #max capactiy here
        def have_enough_item?
          if self.item.stock_qty >= self.quantity
            return true
          else
            if self.quantity_was == nil
              return false
            else
            self.quantity = self.quantity_was
            self.save
            return false
            end
          end
        end
      def set_order_weight
         if 
           self.cart.nil?
         else 
           self.cart.total_weight = self.cart.line_items.to_a.sum {|item| (item.weight)*(item.quantity)}
           self.cart.save
         end
      end
        def over_order_cap?
            if self.quantity > 5
            self.quantity = 5
            self.save
            return true
            end
          return false
        end
        def update_quantity(qty)
          self.quantity += qty
          if self.have_enough_item? == true
          self.save
          end
        end
        def exists_in_collect?(items)
          items.each do |item|
            return true if self.item_id == item.item_id
          end
          return false
        end
        def set_order_total_units
          if 
            self.cart.nil?
          else 
            self.set_cart_units
            self.cart.total_units = self.cart.total_units
            self.cart.save
          end
        end
        def total_price
            item.base_item.price * quantity
        end
    end
```

Routes.rb

```
namespace :shifted_commerce do
    resources :line_items
    resources :items
    resources :base_items
    resource :cart, only: [:show, :update, :destroy] do
            resource :order, only: [:show, :create, :update, :edit, :new] 
        end
end
```

Comment: can you show the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this and try:

```
<%= simple_form_for item, url: shifted_commerce_line_items_path(item), method: :put do |f| %>
```

as per you **routes**

Update:

Sorry it must be `post` but not `put` like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for item, url: shifted_commerce_line_item_path(item), method: :post do |f| %>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be singular?

Comment: I tried this and got the same error... It's as though the path leads to the plural regardless... because POST and get work (the two verbs for the plural path), but the others do not...

Comment: @Peege151 can you show me the controller code of both shifted_commerce and line_items as well as models

Comment: shifted_commerce is just a name space it doesn't have it's own controller...  I've put the line_item controller and model up there. Thanks @anusha

Comment: Ooh, this is really close. I'm getting No route matches [PUT] "/shifted_commerce/line_items.1"  I just need to change the '.' to a '/'...

Comment: @Peege151 please add your routes.rb file so that we can figure it out

Comment: @Peege151 the method must be `post`  but not `put` please check answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65328/discussion-between-peege151-and-anusha).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `<%= simple_form_for ([:shifted_commerce, item]) do |f| %>` **or** 
`<%= simple_form_for item, :url => shifted_commerce_line_item_path do |f| %>`